# How to use List<Data> in android?

Tags: java, android

How should I use `List<Data> dat = new List<Data>();` to temporary store data in my software? `"Data"` is a class in my code with variables(mainly `Strings`). When I try that method it doesn't store data.

Comment: Research Java Generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List` is an interface, so you can't instantiate it (call `new List()`) as it does not have a concrete implementation. To keep it simple, use one of the [existing implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html), for example:

```
List<Data> dat = new ArrayList<Data>();
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Data data = new Data();
//initialise data here
dat.add(data);
```

You would probably benefit from reading the [Java Tutorial on Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Data> lsData = new ArrayList<Data>();

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    Data d = new Data();
    d.fname="fname";
    d.lname="lname";
    lsData.add(d);
}
```

Your Data class (Always make a Bean class to manage data)

```
public class Data
{
  public Data()
  {
  }
  public String fname,lname;
}
```

you can also get your data of particular position

```
String fname = lsData.get(2).fname;
String lname = lsData.get(2).lname;
```